# Getting different outputs on Gitbash and VScode Terminal

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code, python-multithreading, git-bash

Below is the smallest reproducible example I could come up with. In the main function, first an object of `serverUDP` class is created and with the use of threading a function `run` is called which also creates another thread to call another function `RecvData`. Problem is the main thread is not printing `port` value  until the program is stopped with `ctrl + C`. Cannot understand why is this happening.

```
    import socket, simpleaudio as sa
    import threading, queue
    from threading import Thread
    import time

    class ServerUDP:
        def __init__(self):
            while 1:
                try:
                    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                    self.s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
                    self.clients = set()
                    self.recvPackets = queue.Queue()
                    break
                except:
                    print("Couldn't bind to that port")
    
        def get_ports(self):
            return self.s.getsockname()
    
        def RecvData(self, name, delay, run_event):
            while run_event.is_set():
                time.sleep(delay)       
                pass
    
        def run(self, name, delay, run_event):

            threading.Thread(target=self.RecvData, args = ("bob",d1,run_event)).start() #separate thread for listening to the clients
    
            while run_event.is_set():
                time.sleep(delay)
                pass
    
            self.s.close()
    
        def close(self):
            self.s.close()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
            roomserver = ServerUDP()
            run_event = threading.Event()
            run_event.set()
            d1 = 1          
            t = Thread(target= roomserver.run, args = ("bob",d1,run_event))
    
            t.start()
            port = roomserver.get_ports()[1]
            print("port is", port)  
    
            try:
                while 1:
                    time.sleep(.1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("attempting to close threads. Max wait =",d1)
                run_event.clear()
                t.join()
                print("threads successfully closed")
```

**UPD**: I'm on windows platform and was using *VScode* editor for coding and *Git Bash* terminal to run this program. I just ran this on *VScode* terminal and magically it was giving the port number. Is this a known issue in *Git Bash* terminal?

*Adding *VScode* and *Git Bash* tags to know something about it.*

Comment: Did you check with a debugger? Maybe the main thread is waiting in `roomserver.get_ports()`?

Comment: @jurez you are right i just placed `roomserver.get_ports()` just after creating the `roomserver` instance and it is not giving any output.

Comment: what could be the reason for this?

Comment: It is neither printing the `except` statement if it's still in `init` while loop.

Comment: @user13145713 -Have you tried to use other terminals to run this code in VS Code? And have you tested it in a system outside of VS Code? [cmd Terminal in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)

Comment: @JillCheng I think I've added this to the question in UPD section at the bottom. I got it working on the VScode terminal, but every time I used the git bash terminal it is not giving the port number.